# .NET custom configuration section: Configuration.GetSection throws 'unable to locate assembly' exception

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I have created a custom configuration section for a plugin DLL that stores the .config XML in a separate (from the main executable application) file.

Here's a sample of the custom section class:

```
using System;   
using System.Configuration;

namespace PluginFramework.MyConfiguration
{

public class MyConfigurationSettings : ConfigurationSection
{
    private Configuration _Config = null;

    #region ConfigurationProperties     
    /// <summary>
    /// A custom XML section for an application's configuration file.
    /// </summary>
    [ConfigurationProperty("MyProjects", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public MyProjectConfigurationCollection MyProjects
    {
        get { return (MyProjectConfigurationCollection) base["MyProjects"]; }
    }

    // ...
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Private Constructor used by our factory method.
    /// </summary>
    private MyConfigurationSettings () : base () {
        // Allow this section to be stored in user.app. By default this is forbidden.
        this.SectionInformation.AllowExeDefinition =
        ConfigurationAllowExeDefinition.MachineToLocalUser;
    }

    // ...

    #region Static Members  
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current applications &lt;MyConfigurationSettings&gt; section.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ConfigLevel">
    /// The &lt;ConfigurationUserLevel&gt; that the config file
    /// is retrieved from.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The configuration file's &lt;MyConfigurationSettings&gt; section.
    /// </returns>
    public static MyConfigurationSettings GetSection (ConfigurationUserLevel ConfigLevel) 
    {
        string appDataPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string localDataPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap exeMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        exeMap.ExeConfigFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDataPath, @"MyCompany\MyPluginApp\Default.config");
        exeMap.RoamingUserConfigFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDataPath, @"MyCompany\MyPluginApp\Roaming.config");
        exeMap.LocalUserConfigFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(localDataPath, @"MyCompany\MyPluginApp\Local.config");

        System.Configuration.Configuration Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(exeMap,ConfigLevel);
        MyConfigurationSettings myConfigurationSettings = null;

        try {
            myConfigurationSettings = (MyConfigurationSettings)Config.GetSection("MyConfigurationSettings");
        } 
        catch (System.Exception ex) {
            // ConfigurationErrorsException caught here ...
        }
        if (myConfigurationSettings == null) {
            myConfigurationSettings = new MyConfigurationSettings();
            Config.Sections.Add("MyConfigurationSettings", myConfigurationSettings);                    }
        } 
        if(myConfigurationSettings != null) {
            myConfigurationSettings._Config = Config;
        }

        return myConfigurationSettings;
    }       
    #endregion
}
} // PluginFramework.MyConfiguration
```

The .config XML generated when saving 1st time looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- The exception complains about the following line (assembly attributes are compliant): -->
        <section name="MyConfigurationSettings" type="PluginFramework.MyConfiguration.MyConfigurationSettings, PluginFramework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" />
    </configSections>
    <MyConfigurationSettings>
        <!-- Config properties are serialized fine according MyConfigurationSettings 
             properties marked with the ConfigurationProperty attribute ... -->
        <MyProjects>
            <MyProjectConfiguration GUID="{4307AC92-8180-4686-9322-830312ED59AB}">
                <!-- ... more complex configuration elements -->
            </MyProjectConfiguration>
        </MyProjects>
    </MyConfigurationSettings>
</configuration>
```

When this XML is tried to be loaded using `Config.GetSection()` on subsequent runs, I catch a `ConfigurationErrorsException` at the line marked in the XML sample, stating that the assembly `MyPlugin` or one of it's dependencies couldn't be located (please forgive that I'm not posting the original exception message, but I have it only in german, and doubt this text would be helpful here). The inner exception comes from `System.IO` while trying to load the assembly and get reflection to resolve the 'MyConfigurationSettings' class type.

To precise the situation, the code from above is placed inside a framework DLL (assembly), that in turn is referenced by the actual plugin DLL loaded from the main application.

The following UML diagram illustrates the several components' relationships:
[image: Main App plugin and framework components]

After looking around a bit about this problem, I have the feeling it's necessary to strong name (sign) the assembly exporting the `MyConfigurationSettings` class (i.e. `PluginFramework`) and register it with the GAC. I didn't try this yet, and would like to avoid this step for several reasons (before knowing if it could even help and it's the only choice to solve the problem).

So here are the questions (sorry I'm placing actually 4 questions here, but they're so strongly related that it wouldn't make sense to create separate SO questions for them).

1. Could I solve the locating failure problem by strong naming the assembly in question and registering it with the GAC?
2. Stupidly enough the assembly the configuration management complains about, is guaranteed to be loaded (since it calls `Configuration.GetSection()` itself).
   Is there may be a way to register the assembly or the appropriate configuration type de-/serializers explicitly with the `ConfigurationManager` or `Confguration` class?
3. I'm also interested in more information about [Hans Passant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718262/net-custom-configuration-section-configuration-getsection-throws-unable-to-lo#comment20591740_14718262) mentioning this might be a problem caused by the way the (primary) assembly is loaded from the main app. I have no control over this mechanism, and if this causes this behavior inherently I'd like to know if there's a reasonable workaround?
4. Another idea (if anything of the above fails to show a way) is to completely manage a configuration XML format natively (using XML de-/serialization support) and from where to load and merge the configuration files. If this is the most appropriate option, can anyone give good pointers how to do this efficiently (least necessary code for managing paths' and merging)?

**Update:**
Since no one seems to be able to give more insight about this question(s) (the 2 answers don't really get me further), I'm changing to option from 4., doing it all manually.

Comment: One thing I tell you for sure - it not need to be in GAC. First, make sure that your Section Handler lives in the same directory as rest of the code. Second, make sure you use right configuration manager. Third, make sure you have all {<!-- Config properties ... -->} corresponding to properties in your "MyConfigurationSettings" This is to begin...
And Fourth! Looking at your class... I don't think you utilizing it right. You need properties there, not "GetSection". This is whole idea that you call GetSection and framework finds you right section handler where you only have to do -call property

Comment: If the main application is strong-named then any assembly it references must also be strong-named.

Comment: @T.S. Sounds promising! Have a look at some edits to improve the question. The mentioned framework DLL is in the same directory as the plugin DLL, but not in the same directory as the main application executable. I think your points about the configuration properties might be irrelevant (at least for this particular exception, it complains exactly about the line I've marked in the .config XML). About utilization of the `GetSection()` method, this one's intended just for convenience for accessing this specific section, I have no idea where or how I could replace this with a property ...

Comment: @T.S. ... could you elaborate about this point with a sample, or appropriate pointer?

Comment: @groverboy I don't think the main application is strong named, but even if so, the plugin DLL (and framework DLL) are loaded correctly without exceptions (otherwise `MyConfigurationSettings.GetSection()` method wouldn't have bee called at all) ...

Comment: @T.S. Ah, and for addition, I won't ever install the DLL's in the same location as the main application lives, since it's 3rd party and I won't touch their deployment folders directly. The plugin is registered via special registry keys consumed by the main application and simply relies on COM visibility of the plugin.

Comment: @g-makulik what is the framework DLL? Is it strong-named? A weak-named assembly can reference a strong-named assembly but not vice versa.

Comment: @groverboy It isn't. That's exactly the question if it's necessary to do so. The plugin DLL using the framework DLL (effectively the `GetSection()` method shown above) isn't strong named either. Both are registered for COM interop.

Comment: @g-makulik: I think COM interop is not related to the problem.  

The plugin DLL `MyPlugin` references the framework DLL.  

It seems the framework DLL _does not_ reference `MyPlugin`, but code in the framework DLL is expected to resolve this type: `MyPlugin.MyConfiguration.MyConfigurationSettings` (in the XML). If this is true it would explain the "couldn't be located" error; then you need to redesign save/load for the `MyPlugin` configuration.

Comment: This is a problem induced by the way the plugin got loaded.  Avoid Assembly.LoadFile() at all cost.  Get more insight with Fuslogvw.exe

Comment: @HansPassant If this is somehow involved, then by the main app (I don't know how they're actually loading plugins). So avoiding would be out of my scope. Im not using that directly any how ...

Comment: @groverboy May be you didn't get it, framework DLL + the `MyConfigurationSettings` class is self contained. No need to reference the final plugin. (I'll edit the misleading samples)

Comment: @HansPassant Given that s.th. as `Assembly.LoadFile()` is used by the main app, do I have any chance to work around this?

Comment: @HansPassant Bump! Could you give me any further pointers, please?

Comment: you should have to choose the option 4 from the beginning IMHO

Comment: @giammin But implementing all that stuff for generic configuration elements, collections of elements etc. is pretty tedious. But you're right insofar, that this is a typical M$ flaw: They implement a whole bunch of complicated interfaces and classes (as in `System.Configuration`) but you can use it only with their standard use cases :-( ...

Comment: @g-makulik Sad but true! I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 4):

I tried that as well, but I never got it to work like that.
I just figured loading a .config automatically doesn't work for .dll's only for .exe's.
Then I gave up and decided it would be easier to just load the .config file manually.
You can see the full code here: https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Toolpack/blob/master/EANavigator/NavigatorSettings.cs
This is the most relevant part:

```
public NavigatorSettings() {
     Configuration roamingConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming);

     // the roamingConfig now get a path such as C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Sparx_Systems_Pty_Ltd\DefaultDomain_Path_2epjiwj3etsq5yyljkyqqi2yc4elkrkf\9,_2,_0,_921\user.config
     // which I don't like. So we move up three directories and then add a directory for the EA Navigator so that we get
     // C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\GeertBellekens\EANavigator\user.config
     string configFileName =  System.IO.Path.GetFileName(roamingConfig.FilePath);
     string configDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(roamingConfig.FilePath).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName;

     string newConfigFilePath = configDirectory + @"\Geert Bellekens\EANavigator\" + configFileName;
     // Map the roaming configuration file. This
     // enables the application to access 
     // the configuration file using the
     // System.Configuration.Configuration class
     ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
     configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = newConfigFilePath;       

     // Get the mapped configuration file.
     currentConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
     // merge the default settings
     this.mergeDefaultSettings();
 }
```

Accessing a configuration property:

```
public bool trackSelectedElement
{
    get {
        bool result;
        if(bool.TryParse(this.currentConfig.AppSettings.Settings["trackSelectedElement"].Value, out result)) {
            return result;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    set {
        this.currentConfig.AppSettings.Settings["trackSelectedElement"].Value = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't have time now. Later will get real life example.

Comment: So, from further studying your code I see you avoid calling `Configuration.GetSection()` at all and do the property mapping from the loaded and merged configuration(s) by hand (literally). I have added a property access sample to your answer. But I have a number of complex properties in my customized `ConfigurationSettings` (derived from `ConfigurationElementCollection` and `ConfigurationElement`), I'll have to see how to deal with these ...

Comment: I have awarded this answer, because I know who was answering and he deserves the bounty points. Though the answer doesn't solve the original problem or points to an appropriate surrogate solution, so I didn't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

@g-makulik

Here I have a working copy of what was done in real environment and proven to work.

In the App.config file:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="mySectionGroupName">
        <section name="mySectionName" type="MyNamespace.MySectionHandler,MyNamespace" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
....
<mySectionGroupName>
    <mySectionName>
        <add key="MyKey" value="MyKeyValue" />
    </mySectionName>
</mySectionGroupName>
```

In the class where you use config:

```
....
Hashtable ht = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("mySectionGroupName/mySectionName") as Hashtable; 
// when you call this, your handler will do what you want in there
string keyVal = ht["MyKey"] as String;
....
```

The class responsible for config handling:

```
public class MySectionHandler : DictionarySectionHandler 
{
    public override object Create(object parent, object context, XmlNode section) 
    {
        // here do what you want with the value of "MyKey" - "MyKeyValue"
    }
}
```

I hope, this helps

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm not referring to the (main/executable) App config file, but want to create my own for the plugin application, and manage it separately (have a look at the component diagram sample I've posted). Using section groups within the main application configuration might be a solution, but isn't really what I'm looking for.

Comment: The 1st thing I've tried was to adapt the 'type' attribute of the `section` element without the `Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null` stuff, but that didn't help. I'm not sure rewriting my code for a `DictionarySectionHandler` would really solve the assembly load problem of the `Configuation`/`ConfigurationManager` classes.

Comment: @g-makulik-I am telling you exactly what u're looking for.
1-Your plugin can have app.config, which will become "YourPlugIn.dll.config" when code compiled. 2-My example is basically same thing using old `DictionarySectionHandler`. Now you should use `ConfigurationSection`. 3-Remember, I told you, it is used to easy read/write to your 'config' file via properties. Keyword-Properties. Each section value=property. 4-Here is good example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx No need for GAC, versioning, etc. As long as assembly loaded into domain. Did I miss anything?

Comment: _'As long as assembly loaded into domain.'_ I guess exactly this might be the root cause of my problems (see also Hans Passant's comments). I don't have control over this and I'm afraid loading the .config will still fail resolving the `<section />` element.

Comment: One last question, because I really want to try out your sample (besides all doubts): How is `MySectionHandler` registered with the `ConfigurationManager` class? Just by reflection from the calling assembly (e.g. presence of a class inherited from `DictionarySectionHandler` in my plugin)? I see this class is from a very old standard (.NET 1.1) and can imagine the mechanism is still supported for upwards compatibility.

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected the code. `<section name="mySectionName" type="MyNamespace.MySectionHandler,MyNamespace" />`. Yes, this is old way of what you can do with `ConfigurationSection` today. But I still don't see what is your problem. All you need is App.config for your plugin and custom `ConfigurationSection`. The only problem I see is that in order to execute your custom section, its Type needs to be loaded into domain, otherwise it can't be found.

Comment: Again, I don't think the Type for the custom section is loaded into _'domain'_, have a look at the component diagram. I don't even know if the main app is a .NET application. The interaction with the plugin occurs via COM interfaces. Another point is that I don't have a config section format that fits simple key value pairs (see the XML sample from my question), would this be possible with the `DictionarySectionHandler` at all, and if so how would this look like in XML using the `add` element?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not supported by .NET Framework.

1st - it makes sense that your plugin.dll is configured per host application (.exe or web) that is using it (that why it's configurable)

2nd - config files support inheritance (ex: machine.config -> applicationHost.config -> web.config). That what they are designed for. Your off-the-path config would not work properly in that respect.

So, if you need custom configuration for part of app, or plugin, not following .config concepts, make standard XML file, or jsonconfig and load settings from there.

Comment: Yes, looks like these are the facts, but take a look at my comments answer to @giammin. Currently I'm trying to get something working with reusing base classes from `System.Configuration` namespace and my own XML serialization implementation with surrogates for `ConfigurationManager` and `Configuration` classes. I'll finally post the solution here, if I get it working as wanted.

Comment: That is my point exactly. You will use System.Configuration for cosmetic purposes only. It won't work as app.config is expected to work and it will possibly confuse users of your plugin. And you're adding overhead to your implementation with no good reason.

Instead make POCOs and serialize to XML(+XTD if you need intellisense), or serialize to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and haven't found a fully satyisfying solution so far.
Our application loads is compiled with a reference to a configuration section class defined in a dedicated assembly. 
The application is linked with a strongly named assembly but later when the configuration loader tries to read the configuration, fusion traces show that it tries to load a weak name of the same assembly. For some reason, .net fails to see that it is the same assembly and throws a System.IO.FileNotFound exception. 
On working solution in my case is to reference strong names in the configuration.

I have also noticed a strange behavior: Once an assembly is loaded by the .net "configuration loader" with a strong name, further references with a weak name actually succeed ! 
For some reason, the framework "remembers" that the weak name reffers to the same assembly.

Any news from the issue on your end would be interesting !

Comment: I simply gave up on this and have chosen to have my own configuration file formats for my assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`. This should work for `option 2`.